# Invalid aggregate function in ON clause - Joining on arrays overlap/array contains in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to join two tables together based on overlapping contents of two arrays. I have written in Posgresql syntax, which works and I am trying to write in Snowflake SQL.

Below is the code in posgresql:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT profiles.id ) AS count_profiles
FROM panels 
LEFT profiles  AS profiles ON ARRAY[profiles.code::text] <@ ARRAY[panels.profile_codes]
```

Here is my attempt in Snowflake:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT profiles.id ) AS count_profiles
FROM panels
LEFT JOIN profiles ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(panels.profile_codes, array_agg(profiles.code)) = 'TRUE'
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid aggregate function in ON clause

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARRAY_AGG is the aggregate function causing a problem here. It takes all of the codes from your query and puts them into a single array, instead of one array per row. If profiles.code is already an array then you should just need:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT profiles.id ) AS count_profiles
FROM panels
LEFT JOIN profiles ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(panels.profile_codes, profiles.code)
```

Or you may need to use TO_ARRAY: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_array.html

```
... ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(panels.profile_codes, TO_ARRAY(profiles.code))
```

I would need to know more of what your data looks like to clarify further.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and it was really helpful explanation

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just use

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles ON panels.profile_codes = profiles.code
```

What are the data types and cardinality involved here?
Any arrays in `panels.profile_codes` or `profiles.code`?